# Decrypt AAAAAAAAAAAA with vigenere

Tags: cryptography

Maybe someone can help me.

I have to decrypt the Vigenere Chiffre : AAAAAAAAAAAA

This is all what is given. So I have no keylength or something. I think I'm not supposed to do a brute force attack.

I actually do know how the decryption with Vigenere works. I have already written a program for a different text to translate. But my program works for texts consisting of a natural language. I did a frequency analysis of letters, bigrams.. But I don't know I can solve this problem here when there is only one letter 12 times.

Maybe this has something to do with redundancy and unicity length?

It may have to do something with redundancy and unicity length because this was part of my lecture the last time, but i don't know what to do with this information.

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher

Comment: i tried to decode ist on that homepage: There are a lot of possibilities but i didn't find one making sense. I think i need an answer to that example concerning unicity length.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a decryption service. If we allowed all the "please help me decrypt this" questions, we'd be flooded with random strings.

Comment: I think this is supposed to teach you a lesson about Vignere ciphers. You have forgotten to ask yourself, *is it possible*? Here is another encrypted text I made for you: AAAAAAAAAAAA. Can you please decrypt this one for me as well?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your cyphertext is all As, I am going to assume that the key is of the same length as the plaintext (there are edge cases where this is technically untrue, but for decryption purposes it's probably true).

When your Vigenère key is as long as your plaintext, you are effectively using a One-time pad, which is impossible to decrypt.

Comment: To clarify: It's not literally a One-Time Pad, since the key is being set to be equal to the plaintext (hence why the cyphertext is all As).  However, it is information-theoretically secure for roughly the same reasons that a proper One-Time Pad is information-theoretically secure.